# Reading and converting hex to decimal

Tags: mips32

I need to write a MIPS Assembly Language program to read hexadecimal values (one per line) from a file. The file name should be requested and read in from the console. Once the number has been read in, convert it to internal storage. The input format may be either fixed-format, 32-bit, twos compliment values, or variable length signed magnitude. After conversion, the value should be printed to the console.

What I have so far:

```
.data
    fileName: .space 100
    prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the file name: "
    buffer: .space 40966
.text
    main:
    # prompt user for file name
        li $v0, 4           #system call for printing string
        la $a0, prompt1         #load prompt1
        syscall             #print string

    # when entering name of the file, add its entire directory path with double backslashes
        li $v0, 8           #system call for reading string
        la $a0, fileName        #load user input into the address of fileName
        li $a1, 50          # max number of characters the fileName can hold
        syscall             #store user input into fileName


    # converting the string into a null-terminated string
    # replacing last character of fileName with 0 instead of \n

            la   $s0, fileName          # $s0 contains fileName
        add   $s2, $0, $0           # $s2 = 0 (null terminator)
        addi   $s3, $0, '\n'        # $s3 = '\n' (newline escape sequence)

    removeNL:
        lb   $s1, 0($s0)        # load character into $s0
        beq   $s1, $s3, replaceNL       # Break if byte is equal to newline *
        addi   $s2, $s2, 1          # increment counter otherwise
        addi   $s0, $s0, 1          # increment string address
        j   removeNL
    replaceNL:
        sb   $0, 0($s0)         #replace newline with null terminator

    # Open file for reading now that input file name is converted to null-terminated string
        li $v0, 13          # system call for open file
        la $a0, fileName        # address of null-terminated string containing filename
        li $a1, 0           # flags
        li $a2, 0           # mode
        syscall             # open a file
        move $s0, $v0           # save the file descriptor

    # reading from file just opened

        li $v0, 14          # system call for reading from file
        move $a0, $s0           # file descriptor
        la $a1, buffer          # address of input buffer
        li $a2, 40966           # maximum number of char
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. So, which one is your question? If you are stuck just show where and the errors you are getting.

Comment: Basically the input is like this: AB123CA (for example)
And the output is like this: 179381194
It is not like I am getting stuck, it is more like I don't have enough knowledge about MIPS to understand how to code in it.

Comment: Add this information to your post (edit it) and you should focus your problem making a question like: I introduce this data (Input sample) and I have got this result (Output sample), but I am looking for this other result (Expected Output sample). What am I doing wrong?